# Zend2 Form - set attributes to options in select element

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I wonder how to add some attributes to select's options in Zend 2. My form element looks like this:

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'brand_name',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Choose brand',
            'value_options' => $this->getBrands(),
        ),
    ));
```

So it's populate select looking similar to this:

```
<select name="brand_name"><option value="1">aaaa</option></select>
```

But I want to achieve something like this:

```
<select name="brand_name"><option value="1" class="test">aaaa</option></select>
```

And the classes should be different, depends on particular option. Is it possible? Why am I trying this? I need to add jquery plugin - chained which needs classes for options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, array of parent select value_options should look like this:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
        $models[] = array(
          'label' => $item->model_name, 
          'attributes' => array('class' => $item->id_brand_list), 
          'value' => $item->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data were `array` that you preferred getting from `sql` or `db`,  you can code like:

```
public function getOptionsForDataSelect()
{
    $dbAdapter = $this->_adapter;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_name ORDER BY db_name ASC";
    $statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute();

    $selectData = array();
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        $selectData[] = array(
            'label' => $res['label_data'],
            'attributes' => array(
                'data-key' => $res['data_id']
            ),
            'value' => $res['value_id']
        );
        // $selectData[$res['id']] = $res['name'];
    }
    return $selectData;
}
```